# Why can't I modify the axes from a JavaFX LineChart?

Tags: charts, plot, javafx, linechart

I got a `LineChart` which actually hold two axes. I really need to manipulate the bounds for xAxis and the ticking, however I can't get the axis as a `NumberAxis`, I just get it as an `Axis` for which I can't get the setLowerBound method, neither upperBound or tick settings....

How can I solve this?

Comment: If you have created the mentioned axis as a NumberAxis, you can safely down cast the Axis to NumberAxis.

Answer (score 1):

As @uluk-biy points out, you can safely use an up-cast here, if the `Axis` was created as a `NumericAxis`:

```
NumericAxis numericAxis = (NumericAxis) axis;
```